# As an alternative to Objective-C, which language works better?

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa

I would like to know which one of these languages brings better functionalities on a mac for programming mac os x?

Comment: possible duplicate of [advantages and disadvantages of using MacRuby over Objective-C (Mac OS X)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857004/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-macruby-over-objective-c-mac-os-x)

Comment: here is a comparison of two alternative for objective-c , ruby or python or perhaps any better language.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Ruby and Python are fairly similar to each other, and very different from Objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004936

They both have the same level of integration. You simply get your language of choice's benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped a lot.